# alt key does not work in sublime 3 Terminus

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3

I use Sublime 3 Terminus on a Mac. Recently, the <kbd>alt</kbd> key does not work. For example, to generate a `|`, I used <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

This does work in atext file, but not in Terminus. When I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, I get:`(arg: 7)`

What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: Have you recently installed any other plugins?

Comment: No, as far as I remember, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular case you can add this keymap config:
Sublime Text > Settings... > Key Bindings

```
{ "keys": ["alt+7"], "command": "terminus_keypress", "args": {"key": "|"}, "context": [{"key": "terminus_view"}] }
```

I am not sure if there is a general way to fix this.
In the Terminus Key Bindings settings you can get some inspiration for other configurations.

This [section (Alt-Left/Right to move between words (Unix))](https://github.com/randy3k/Terminus#alt-leftright-to-move-between-words-unix) of the Terminus readme might also be relevant. It shows how to set bindings via bash/zsh profile.